# How can I use "A simple connected graph has an Euler Circuit iff .." to show/prove something?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

We are given the following theorem in our textbook (Discrete Mathematics, Rosen)

> A connected multigraph with at least two vertices has an Euler circuit if and only if each of its vertices has an even degree.

My main confusion lies in understanding the **iff** part. I understand that it means "equivalence" and "if and only if" however, I am having trouble understanding how to use it to show/prove something.

I have seen that when we have an **iff** statement, we have to show something both ways i.e. $\implies$ and $\impliedby$; in this case, does that mean have to show:

1. We have an Euler circuit $\implies$ each vertex has even degree
2. If all the vertices have an even degree then ($\impliedby$) then Euler circuit?

I have a feeling that this is incorrect. Can someone please clarify this?

Thanks for your time

Comment: What you have is correct. If the graph has an Euler circuit, then each vertex has even degree, and if each vertex has even degree, then the graph has an Euler circuit.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for your reply. If you could post your comment as an answer, I would be more than happy to accept it! :)

Comment: Done! I also added just a little information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is correct. On the one hand if the graph has an Euler circuit, then each vertex has even degree; this is the easier direction. On the other hand, if the graph is connected and each vertex has even degree, then the graph has an Euler circuit; this is a bit harder. (If it’s not connected, each component has an Euler circuit.)